# How to code open ended questions

Tags: spss

I have some open-ended questions on a survey which i designed using survey monkey and had exported the responses from survey monkey directly to spss which  means that the responses to the short answer questions are already in string form on spss now. I want to convert them to numeric data instead by grouping the commonly occurring themes together. I am not very good with spss but I watched a tutorial online which used the transform button to recode in to different variables but wouldn't that be impossible if I have 566 responses which are all completely worded differently?

I would appreciate any help! it's for my thesis!! 
Thanks

Comment: This class of problem, in which one wants to somehow transform free-form text into quantitative data, is usually called "content analysis" in the social sciences.

Comment: What do you want to do with the numeric data?  I think you want to cluster it into less than ~550 bins, and then look at membership and relation to other variables.  Bag-of-words style analysis might be a good starting point, though I don't know anything about doing it in SPSS.  If you were using "R" then I would suggest something like the "qdap" library. [link](https://trinker.github.io/qdap/) [vignette](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/packages/qdap_vignette.html)

Comment: sorry for the double, but time ran out on the previous one... The current answers are saying "get human help".  You might consider using "the mechanical turk". [link](https://requester.mturk.com/)

Answer (score 6):

You'll likely need to got through and read each response and then code it according some some sort of standardized rubric.  You may have to record the respondent ID number in a spreadsheet along with your numeric recode.  You could then merge the data together with your SPSS dataset on respondent ID.  Or you could just enter the codes into the SPSS dataset directly (e.g. create a new variable next to the verbatim response and enter in your numeric score/code).

That being said, the "right" way to do this is to score the data more than once.  For example, you should assign the codes according to the rubric and then someone else should independently score the data using the same rubric without looking at your scores.  Then you should compare the scores for internal consistency using something like inter-rater reliability ([IRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)).  You should be able to find plenty of information on IRR on this site and on the internet.

Yes, this is a bit of a daunting task given the volume of data.  Note too that this is not the only approach you can use.  There are some automated methods (e.g. clustering methods and text-mining algorithms) that can do this for you as well.  However, the quality can be largely variable.

Comment: It's just 566 answer, not that much of a work.

Comment: $\times$ 2 at least.  And we have no idea how long the responses are, so it's impossible to say it's not that much work.  If each responses was 20 pages in length, I'd say more than 20 would be painful to handle manually.

Answer (score 1):

*@StatsStudent* has already provided a nice answer that I agree with, but let me add to it. Instead of coding the answers yourself by hand, you should rather employ *independent coders* that will do that for you.

Imagine that you, as a researcher, are interested in obtaining a certain result and so during the coding you are more prone to (semi-consciously) "see" certain themes in the answers written by responders. This would distort your results.

There is also a reason to employ more then one coder to code the same answers (or at least a part of them): imagine that a certain coder has some kind of "bias" in his reading of the answers (say, he always considers them as "positive") - if you used his coding, the results would get biased. If you employ more than one coder, then you can compare their codings so to assess their agreement/reliability (almost for sure they won't be the same, they never are) and on another hand, you could assume that the more codings you have the less biased they get on average (e.g. there are both "positive" and "negative" coders, so in the end they cancel out).

Comment: Where is he going to find independent coders? It's his *thesis*

Comment: @Aksakal As far as I remember, when you are on university you have friends who sometimes have some spare time... There really *are* possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by @StatsStudent. If you find it painful to code, and existing software does not apply to your task, you can externalise / delegate this work to a "volunteer" human that could "learn" from that experience. Explain to him that his work is very important too but resources are limited (as it is time). This is what they tell you also at work, so I guess its acceptable.

Comment: Should "as it is time" read "as is time"?